# How to update embedded column's property in orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am facing an issue while updating an embedded field's property in Orientdb.

Below are the steps to reproduce the issue:

```
CREATE VERTEX Foo set value = { 'abc-def-hgi':"blah blah", '1ab-2cd-3ef': "aaaaa", '345-jkl-mno':'ppppp' }, id = 1
CREATE VERTEX Foo set value = { 'abc-def-hgi':"mmmmm", '1ab-2cd-3ef': "nmnmnmn", '345-jkl-mno':'qqqq' }, id = 2
CREATE VERTEX Foo set value = { 'abc-def-hgi':"lorem ipsum", '1ab-2cd-3ef': "mmmmm", '345-jkl-mno':'llll' }, id = 3
```

Property "value" has been declared as of type "Embedded".

Now, I want to update record with id "1" for "abc-def-hgi" property in column "value".

I have tried with below queries, but neither of them worked:

```
update Foo set value["abc-def-hgi"] = "new new" where id = 1
update Foo set value.abc-def-hgi = "new new" where id = 1
```

It seems that it is having problem with hypen ("-") in the field's property name.

I am using Orientdb's version: 2.2.11

Note: I have looked upon issues in orientdb Git repo, where I found [this](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4353). Not sure whether it is related to my issue or not, but it's not working at my end.

Any help would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself the problem is with -.

If you try with a field without - the following query works.

Example

```
update Foo set value.prop = "myprop1" where id=1
```

If you try to create a field with - , you got an exception.

**UPDATE**

To create a property with hyphen you could use this command

```
create property foo.`abc-def-hgi` string
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I know it works without hyphen. But,  I need to use hyphen ("-") in the property name. Isn't it at all possible, is that what you mean to say?

Comment: Yes, because when I tried to create a field with -, I got an exception, I think that is not possibile.

Comment: Regarding "create property foo.`abc-def-hgi` string", I am not using any property with hyphen here, my property in the example is "value", and it's of type "Embedded", and it contains object with dynamic properties in it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the usage of '-' in the names of the properties you can use the quotes as Alessandro says or disable the "Strict" value in database option (in that case you are rolling back to the old parser that was a little bit less rigid)